# Example for file upload to nextcloud in PHP

Tags: php, nextcloud

I searched for working example to upload a file to a new installed nextcloud.

Can anybody provide some sample code?

I found one script usint sabre dav but this only results in `App not installed` error.

Another script used curl_exec gets `file not found` from nextcloud:

```
$fp = fopen("test.jpg", "r");

$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mcloud.XXXX.at/index.php/s/fo7W3MMRnas9B3G");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxx:yyyy"); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PUT, true); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize("test.jpg"));
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
$ret = curl_exec($c);
```

EDIT:
with sabre DAV i also tested the following code without success:

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$settings = array(
    'baseUri' => 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.at/remote.php/dav',
    'userName' => 'test1',
    'password' => 's8R87-JCZN6-tf3Eb-aHLyj-zPzKW'
);

$client = new Sabre\DAV\Client($settings);

// Upload a file
$upload_result = $client->request('PUT', 'test-upload.txt', 'This will be written to the txt file');
```

the result with sabre dav was always html response with "App not installed" message

Comment: Have a look at this: http://sabre.io/dav/davclient/
Never used but by the looks of it seems like it is the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Klamberext: i already tried it wihout success (just edited my post)

Comment: Review this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59328246/uploading-a-file-to-nextcloud-with-php-curl-in-postman-but-the-file-uploaded-is/68993056#68993056

Answer (score 2):

already found the solution.
the plai php-curl works but i had to change the URL to:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://XXXXXXXX/remote.php/webdav/SUBPATH/test.jpg");
```